# Inserting textfield value to core data object

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I am trying to store a UITextView content to a core data object if a condition is true:

```
    ...

    //implementation
    NSString *textActualDescription;

    ...

    //save action    

    ...

    //
     NSString *descriptionText = ToDoDescriptionTextField.text;//assign text from UITextView to descriptionText.
    [textActualDescription isEqualToString:@"Enter ToDo Description here or leave this message to enter a blank description."];//assign string to textActualDescription.

    if ([descriptionText isEqualToString:textActualDescription]){


    [favoriteThing setValue:descriptionText forKey:@"thingDescription"];//if equal.

    }
    else {
        [favoriteThing setValue:@"No description" forKey:@"thingDescription"];//if not equal.
    }
    ...
    //saving core data
```

The app stores perfectly all the rest of attributes, but in this case, the comparison is not  recognised in any case, and always takes the 'else' option. As default the UITextView ToDoDescriptionTextField text is the same as the string assigned to 'textActualDescription'.
What is wrong there?

Comment: Check the lines before the `if`.  You're not assigning anything to `textActualDescription`.  Rather your sending a `isEqualToString:` message to it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and comment, I now know what i was doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textActualDescription` is not being assigned any value. Instead of:

`[textActualDescription isEqualToString:@"Enter ToDo Description here or leave this message to enter a blank description."];//assign string to textActualDescription.`

use:

`textActualDescription = @"Enter ToDo Description here or leave this message to enter a blank description.";//assign string to textActualDescription.`